# How to generate hashing password with the SHA-1 algorithm in Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, ionic-framework

I have a requirement to send the **password** value to back-end in the form of hash using **SHA-1 hashing algorithm**. Please guide me how can i achieve this objective.

I have googled and found a [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sha1) which is one native js function in npm package, but is there any way i can use it in my Ionic 2 application ? Or any other way like adding an external [js](https://github.com/emn178/js-sha1/tree/master/src) file in the application and use the function in it to build the password hash.

Comment: https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/

Comment: SHA-1 is a one-way hash, it is not encryption. If you are going to be encrypting you want AES-256 with a unique initialization vector for each item.

Comment: Apologies, i unknowing wrote encryption instead of hash. @Chase: thank for correcting me, its always good to know the correct term.

Comment: @sumeet kumar: provided information was great, and it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use CryptoJS

Install the package via NPM

```
npm install crypto-js --save
```

Import it into your .ts file

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
```

Utilize the SHA1 as follows:

```
var hash= CryptoJS.SHA1("hello");
```

Like chase mentioned above, this is hashing, not encryption.

Comment: The proper way to import the library into Ionic is: import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

Answer (score 3):

I implemented the solution above for Ionic 3 but I got an error message. You also have to install types using:

```
npm install @types/crypto-js
```

Then it works.

Comment: Thank you for updating the solution, this could definitely help someone.